# PHP search folder for user pic set default image if nothing found

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

Im using a great opensource script called [bulletproof](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof) allowing users to upload a profile picture.

The profile picture gets stored in a folder as specified. Im not using any mysql.

**What I would like to do is display a default user img if user has not uploaded a profile picture.**

If he/she has uploaded a profile picture the default img will obviously get overwritten to the pic uploaded by user.

The problem comes in on how would I display the default profile pic, if user has not uploaded anything? Keeping in mind im not using any mysql.

When an image is uploaded it is assigned the name of the user ID, like so

```
<img src="imgs/users/1.png" style="width:100%" height="125px">
```

Would you say it is the most efficient way to search the folder for an image match on the name userID?

If something is found display uploaded img else display default img?  Or should I rather go a mysql route?

Hope the question is clear, if you need any more info please drop me a comment below. Any advice and/or help appreciated.

EDIT: this is what I eventually came up with, probably not most efficient but does the job

```
 function getProfilePic($userID){

        $filename ='imgs/users/'.$userID.'.png';
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            return $img = $userID.'png';
            exit();
        }
        $filename='imgs/users/'.$userID.'.jpg';
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            return $img = $userID.'jpg';
            exit();
        }
        else{
            return $img = 'default.jpg';    
            exit();
        }
    }

 <img src="imgs/users/<?php echo getProfilePic($userID) ?>" style="width:100%" height="125px" />
```

Comment: set a default value as `/path/to/default/image.png` to the field (a database, a text file or whatever) where you hold references about user images.

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code that would do this?

Comment: @geeves yes I have

Comment: Please post the code that you wrote.  That helps us help you.

Comment: @geeves please see edit, cheerz

Comment: Thanks for doing it. One hour after you posted the code you got an excellent answer below: @sukalogika

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:
PHP file_exists() Function

Reference
https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_filesystem_file_exists.asp

Or modify this code :)

```
<?php

function show_image($user_id){
    if(file_exists("imgs/users/$user_id.png")){
        return "<img src=\"imgs/users/$user_id.png\" style=\"width:100%\" height=\"125px\">";
    }
    else{
        return "<img src=\"imgs/users/default.png\" style=\"width:100%\" height=\"125px\">";
    }
}

echo show_image(1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_exists` to check if the image exists, and then use the default image if that returns false.

Comment: Hi Netrilix thank you for your answer, i modified my function as follows but it keeps on returning default....`function getProfilePic($userID){
 
 $filename ='imgs/users'.$userID.'.png';
 if(file_exists($filename)){
  return $img = $userID;
 }
 else{
  return $img ='default'; 
 }
}`

Comment: You forgot your slash :) $filename ='imgs/users/'.$userID.'.png';

Answer (score 0):

At the time of image upload, make user-wise image. Means image name must be the name of username or id.

At the time of showing image put a if condition to check if logged-in user image exist using its id or name in `file_exists`. If not then load the default image.